# Explicit formula for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to construct an infinite series which goes like this:

$\Large x^2+x^{2x^2}+x^{2x^{2x^2}}+x^{2x^{2x^{2x^2}}}+...$

Therefore, I need an explicit formula of the sequence

$\Large x^2,x^{2x^2},x^{2x^{2x^2}},x^{2x^{2x^{2x^2}}},...$

I tried this recursive formula first, but it turned out to be incorrect:

$(a_{n+1})=(a_n)^{(a_n)}$

Does there even exist an explicit (or at least a recursive) formula for this sequence?

Comment: Is this $(x^2)^{(x^2)^{(x^2)}}\ldots$?

Comment: Recursive definition seems to be $a_i=\begin{cases}x^2 & \text{for } i = 1\\ x^{2a_{i-1}} = (x^2)^{a_{i-1}} & \text{for } i > 1\end{cases}$

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @CiaPan: Are you sure? To me your formula seems like: $x^2,(x^2)^{x^2},((x^2)^{x^2})^{(x^2)^{x^2}},...$, which be $x^2,x^{2x^2},x^{2x^2*x^{2x^2}},...$

Comment: @de_dust Rising a power to a power is equivalent to multiplying exponents: $(A^B)^X = A^{B\cdot X}$ so the third expression from your comment is $((x^2)^{x^2})^{(x^2)^{x^2}} = (x^2)^{(x^2)\cdot (x^2)^{x^2}} = (x^2)^{(x^2)^{1+x^2}}$ while my formula gives $a_3 = (x^2)^{a_2} = (x^2)^{(x^2)^{a_1}} = (x^2)^{(x^2)^{x^2}} = x^{2x^{2x^2}}$, as desired.

Comment: @CiaPan: You're correct. I was confused by all the powers

Comment: @CiaPan: But do you know an explicit formula, too? Or a method to construct the series without using the formula?

Comment: @de_dust No, I do not know the formula, but replace $(x^2)$ with $a$ and then search for [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)–related topics.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation