# Ordinary differential equation/ successive approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

My assignment is to solve this initial value problem by successive approximation:

$y'=2xy$

$y(0)=1$

I have calculated the first three iterations:

$y_0=1$

1. $y_1=1+x^2$
2. $y_2=1+x^2+x^{2x^2}$
3. $y_3=1+x^2+x^{2x^2}+x^{2x^{2x^2}}$

Well, the pattern is recognizable already. The only problem is:

How do I construct an infinite series with this?

I think I would need to find an explicit formula for the sequence first ([see my other question regarding this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542652/explicit-formula-for-a-sequence)).

But what if there isn't any explicit formula? Are there any other methods to turn the sum into an infinite series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can solve the equation explicitly by separation of variables, the solution is $e^{x^2}$.

Second, you should not have those tetrations in your approximations. The initial approximation is a polynomial, and the integral of a polynomial is a polynomial, so your approximations should all be polynomials. For instance

$$y_0 = 1 \\
y_1 = 1+\int_0^x 2z(1) dz= 1+x^2 \\
y_2 = 1+\int_0^x 2z(1+z^2) dz = 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}$$

etc. (Here $z$ is a dummy integration variable.) What you get should be easy to recognize, especially given the explicit solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your calculations for $y_2$ and $y_3$:
$$\begin{align}
y_2(x)&=1+\int_0^x2\,t\,(1+t^2)\,dt=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2},\\
y_3(x)&=1+\int_0^x2\,t\,(1+t^2+\frac{t^4}{2})\,dt=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{6}.
\end{align}$$
Can you see the pattern?

Comment: Julian, you have a typo on the result of your integration.

Comment: No hay problema.